# Is it possible to create a constructor for a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

I am trying to call all the virtual functions in the derived class and then define them outside as the `saving` class, however I am looks like I am not properly defined my constructor class and I cannot seem to fix it.

I am using the constructor from `class accountInfo` to store the virtual functions and the protected members and I want `balance` to update using `saving(current_balance,current_interest);`. However, I am sure I have a logical error somewhere but I cannot find it. I know I do not use the constructor `accountInfo(double addBalance, double intRate);` because I want to update the value of balance using the derived class not the parent class

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class accountInfo{

public:
  accountInfo();
  accountInfo(double addBalance, double intRate);
  virtual void deposit(double amount);
  virtual void withdraw(double amount);
  virtual double calcInt();
  virtual double monthlyProc();
  void virtual print();
  ~accountInfo();
protected:
  double balance = 0;
  int numDeposits = 0;
  int numWithdraws = 0;
  double annual_Interest = 0;
  double monthlyServiceFee = 10;
  bool status = false;
};

class saving: public accountInfo{

public:

  saving(double addBalance, double intRate);
  void print();
  void withdraw(double amount);
  void deposit(double amount);
  double calcInt();
  double monthlyProc();

};

void saving::deposit(double amount){   //how to call back the base function
  if(balance >=25){
      status = true;
      balance +=amount;
      numDeposits++;
  }
  else
      status = false;
      cout << "Balance is below 25" << endl;
}



accountInfo::accountInfo(){}

accountInfo::accountInfo(double addBalance, double intRate){

  balance = addBalance;
  annual_Interest = intRate;
}

saving::saving(double addBalance, double intRate){

  balance = addBalance;
  annual_Interest = intRate;
}


void saving::withdraw(double amount){

  balance -= amount;
  numWithdraws++;

}

double saving::calcInt(){

  double monthlyRate = annual_Interest/12;
  double monthlyInterest = balance * monthlyRate;
  return balance + monthlyInterest;

}

double saving::monthlyProc(){   //how to call calcInt to delete the following

  balance -= monthlyServiceFee;
  numWithdraws = 0;
  numDeposits = 0;
  monthlyServiceFee = 0;

  return balance;
}

void saving::print(){

  cout <<"current balance " <<balance << endl;
  cout << "Interest Rate "<<annual_Interest << endl;
  cout << "number of deposits " << numDeposits << endl;
  cout << "number of withdraws " <<  numWithdraws << endl;
  cout << "monthlyServiceFee "  << monthlyServiceFee << endl;
}


accountInfo::~accountInfo(){}


int main(){
  double current_balance = 0;
  double current_interest = 0;
  double money, money0;
//accountInfo obj0;
accountInfo obj = accountInfo(100,100);

char option;

while(option != 'Q'){
cout << "Select action" << endl;
cin >> option;
option = toupper(option);
saving obj1(current_balance,current_interest); 
switch(option){

  case('A'):
  {
  cout << "Please input your balance and interest rate: " << endl;
  cin >> current_balance;
  cin >> current_interest;
  obj1 = saving(current_balance,current_interest);
  }
  break;

  case('D'):
  cout << "Money to deposit" << endl;
  cin >> money;
  obj1.deposit(money);
  break;

  case('W'):
  cout << "Money to withdraw" << endl;
  cin >> money0;
  obj1.withdraw(money0);
  break;

  case('P'):
  obj1.print();
  break;

  case ('Q'):
  option = 'Q';
  break;

}
}
  // cout << "the balance after interest is " <<obj.calcInt() << endl;
  // cout << "money after the monthly services " << obj.monthlyProc() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Use the constructor like `accountInfo::accountInfo(double addBalance, double intRate) : balance(addBalance), annual_Interest(intRate) { ... }`. Your subclass should probably also call the parent class constructor: `saving::saving(double addBalance, double intRate) : accountInfo(addBalance, intRate) { }` which avoids re-implementing it.

Comment: Some things that you might want to learn about are the use of [initialization lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and [the `override` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)

Comment: You might also want to learn about [virtual destructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Virtual_destructor). You're missing definitions for the `accountInfo` functions so maybe you actually want [pure virtual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class) functions?

Comment: I think this could be a good question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (after you've fixed the linker errors of course).

Answer (score 3):

If you ever have a class:

```
class Base {
    public:
        Base();
};
```

and some other derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base{
    public:
        Derived();
};
```

The proper way to call a parent class' constructor is like this:

```
Derived::Derived() : Base() {
    // Some implementation
}
```

So you call the constructor after a `:`. So in your case, it would probably look something like this:

```
saving::saving(double addBalance, double intRate) : accountInfo(addBalance, intRate) {
    // Some implementation
}
```

This will call `accountInfo()`'s constructor when `saving()` is constructed.

Comment: The base constructor need to be public, protected or the derived class be a friend to access the constructor of the base.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks. Fixed.